# Passing a dict of dict with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm working on a website running on Django.
I need to pass data from the Javascript to my Python code with Ajax.

Here's my code:

```
// Javascript file
   function myFunc() {
        {...} // Generate var 'values' which is a dict of dict {{},{}...}
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        $.ajax({
                url : "holt/",
                type : "POST",
                data : values,
                success : function (json) {
                   console.log(json)
                },
                error : function () {
                    alert("Error Ajax");
                }
            })
    }
```

My view in python:

```
  class getHolt(TemplateView):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargd):
            pass 
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargd):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                data = dict(request.POST)
                h = Holt(data)
                response_data, success = h.get_holt(2021, no_freeze=True)
                return HttpResponse(
                    json.dumps(response_data),
                    content_type="application/json"
                )
```

However when I run this, with:

> Javascript values

```
values= {
    "1":{"data_2013":"49105","data_2014":"92620","data_2015":"30000","data_2016":"1945000"},
    "2":{"data_2013":"2885906","data_2014":"2876120","data_2015":"2882653","data_2016":"2787520"},
    "3":{"data_2013":"29201124","data_2014":"29470635","data_2015":"29383195","data_2016":"30154361"}}
```

I receive this in my Python code:

```
print request.POST
```

> < QueryDict: {u'1[data_2014]': [u'92620'], u'1[data_2015]':
>   [u'30000'], u'3[data_2013]': [u'29201124'], u'3[data_2014]':
>   [u'29470635'],...}>

```
print dict(request.POST)
```

> {u'1[data_2014]': [u'92620'], u'1[data_2015]':
>   [u'30000'], u'3[data_2013]': [u'29201124'], u'3[data_2014]':
>   [u'29470635'],...}

Why don't I receive a dict of dict like I've send ?

What does Ajax do to the data before "sending" them ?

Thank You

JS dictionnary

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
   {"1":{"data_2013":"49105","data_2014":"92620","data_2015":"30000","data_2016":"1945000"},"2":{"data_2013":"2885906","data_2014":"2876120","data_2015":"2882653","data_2016":"2787520"},"3":{"data_2013":"29201124","data_2014":"29470635","data_2015":"29383195","data_2016":"30154361"}}
```

Comment: Do you really get different values to what your javascript sends?.. Django's request post is a querydict containing the values. It doesn't contain the raw post data, you could probably find that in `request.body` although you're better off learning how to use the post data

Comment: Hi thanks for helping. Yeah I didn't know that request.POST worked like that. However I've found the values in the body, but the format is a like above: 1[data_xxx]=1234.  Maybe I am doing this completly wrong ?

Comment: well why don't you show what your dictionary is in javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jquery will breaks your js dict(it's called object in js) into multiple variables before sending via ajax so there is no dict on the python side , basically you can't pass a dictionary from js to python  via ajax ... however they both understand json .

so you need to json encode your dict before sending them

```
   $.ajax({
            url : "holt/",
            type : "POST",
            data : { 'values' : JSON.stringify(values) } ,
            success : function (json) {
               console.log(json)
            },
            error : function () {
                alert("Error Ajax");
            }
        })
```

and decode them in the python view

```
dict_ = json.loads(request.POST.get('values'))
```

btw , i highly recommend using firebug if you are using ajax so can see whtas going on

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, it work perfectly. (Thanks for the firebug tip)