# Parsing array of objects to Django backend from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I have some data that I am gathering using JavaScript which I and trying to parse to my Django backend using an Ajax request. However the array is very different when console logging in the JavaScript and printing out in the python back end.

**JavaScript:**

```
function confirm_add_all_product(e) {
    let data_products = []
    let table = e.closest("thead").nextElementSibling.childNodes
    table.forEach(function(i) {
      let row = {}

      row.record_id = (i.children[7].children[1].firstChild.getAttribute('data-record-id'))
      row.product_id = (i.children[7].children[1].firstChild.getAttribute('data-product-id'))
      row.foil = (i.children[2].textContent)
      row.condition = (i.children[3].textContent)
      row.language = (i.children[4].textContent)
      row.quantity = (i.children[7].children[0].value)

      data_products.push(row)
    });

    console.log(data_products)

    $.ajax({
    url: "/integrations/card/inventory_update_all/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
      data_products: data_products,
    },
    success: function (response) {},
    error: function (request, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

**Python:**

```py
@login_required
def inventory_update_all(request):
    print(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

**JS Console Log:**

```
[
    {
        "record_id": "",
        "product_id": "",
        "foil": "false",
        "condition": "nm",
        "language": "eng",
        "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
        "record_id": "",
        "product_id": "",
        "foil": "false",
        "condition": "nm",
        "language": "eng",
        "quantity": "2"
    }
]
```

**Current Python Print:**

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [''], 'data_products[0][record_id]': [''], 'data_products[0][product_id]': [''], 'data_products[0][foil]': ['false'], 'data_products[0][condition]': ['nm'], 'data_products[0][language]': ['eng'], 'data_products[0][quantity]': ['1'], 'data_products[1][record_id]': [''], 'data_products[1][product_id]': [''], 'data_products[1][foil]': ['false'], 'data_products[1][condition]': ['nm'], 'data_products[1][language]': ['eng'], 'data_products[1][quantity]': ['2']}>
```

**Expected Python Print:**

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [''], 'data_products': {['record_id': '', 'product_id': '', 'foil': 'false', 'condition': 'nm', 'language': 'eng', 'quantity': '1'],['record_id': '', 'product_id': '', 'foil': 'false', 'condition': 'nm', 'language': 'eng', 'quantity': '2']}}>
```

I would like the data in the python backend to look like the expected so I am able to loop through each `data_products` record and add it to the database. I am unsure why the format of the data is changing so much between the Ajax request and the backend.

Comment: Try `print(request.POST.get['data_products'])`

Comment: That returns `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698371/passing-a-dict-of-dict-with-ajax.   Does this help?

Comment: yes that does thank you. I will mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

With the fact that the provided link in the comment had slightly different outputs. Just so that no one else have to waste 20 minutes trying to find the question with an answer instead of reading the comments I'll put this answer here.

The outputs like

```
<QueryDict: {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [''], 
    'data_products[0][record_id]': [''], 
    'data_products[0][product_id]': [''], 
    'data_products[0][foil]': ['false'], 
    'data_products[0][condition]': ['nm'], 
    'data_products[0][language]': ['eng'], 
    'data_products[0][quantity]': ['1'], 
    'data_products[1][record_id]': [''], 
    'data_products[1][product_id]': [''], 
    'data_products[1][foil]': ['false'], 
    'data_products[1][condition]': ['nm'], 
    'data_products[1][language]': ['eng'], 
    'data_products[1][quantity]': ['2']
}>
```

Happen when trying to send an actual json object instead of a string of json.

So the relevant part in [Passing a dict of dict with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698371/passing-a-dict-of-dict-with-ajax) is

```
...

            data : { 'values' : JSON.stringify(values) } ,
...
```